# Swift Mapkit example project

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am new to iOS environment . I have created a map kit app for learning . I added delegate to viewController and also did reference outlet but simulation screen still blank here is my code what is wrong ?

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Places{
var latitute : CLLocationDegrees
var longtitut : CLLocationDegrees
var placeLoc : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var theAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation?

init (latit : CLLocationDegrees, long :
    CLLocationDegrees, mytitle : String ,mysubTitle : String){
    self.latitute = latit
    self.longtitut = long
    setLocation()
    setAnnotations(mytitle, subtitle: mysubTitle)
}


func setLocation ( ) {

    placeLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitute, self.longtitut)
}

func  setAnnotations (title : String , subtitle : String ) {

    theAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    theAnnotation?.coordinate = placeLoc!
    theAnnotation?.title = title
    theAnnotation?.subtitle = subtitle


}}
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var myMapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var latDelta : CLLocationDegrees
    var longDelta : CLLocationDegrees

    longDelta = 0.01
    latDelta = 0.01

    var theSpan : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

    var place1 : Places = Places(latit: 45.995079, long: 54.121006, mytitle: "MyHome", mysubTitle: "Home Sweet Home")
    var theRegion : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(place1.placeLoc!, theSpan)

    self.myMapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)
    self.myMapView.addAnnotation(place1.theAnnotation)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

[image]

Comment: when you say blank, is it a black screen?

Comment: White blank screen like there is no map view on storyboard but actually there is

Comment: Can you post an image of the story board? - For what it's worth you should just do the above in code and forget the storyboards.

Comment: It all looks correct, did you definitely instantiate your ViewController in the app delegate and add it to the Window as a root view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the constraints off to start with and re-run the application, you should see the map appear. Then use the Pin button in the design area to set the constraints. If you want it to fill the view set each vales to 0 and enable the I bar adjacent to each value.

Remember that Xcode 6 is in beta and can be a bit flakey. Also, you might want to confirm its your constraints, go to Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy and turn the wireframe on to see where your view is ending up.

Final tip, turn on the assistant editor and change it to preview the storyboard so that you can see how the constraints are impacting on the map view.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code in vieDidLoad method,no need to create another swift file.It will display annotation with map view.Maybe it will helpful you

```
     var latDelta : CLLocationDegrees
     var longDelta : CLLocationDegrees

     latDelta = 0.01
    longDelta = 0.01

    let theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta , longDelta)
    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.068452, longitude: 80.25812)
    let theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, theSpan)
    mapview.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)

    var anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    anotation.coordinate = location
    mapview.addAnnotation(anotation)
```